# SMSComposeTask customising

Tags: windows-phone-7, customization

Is there a way to customize the graphical interface of "SMSComposeTask"?

```
private void btnSendSMS_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        smsComposeTask.To = "123-45-45";
        smsComposeTask.Body =
            "Hello! This is a test sms message!";
        smsComposeTask.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently , the Windows Phone 7 does not supports directly sending the sms without the SMS Compose Screen .

We may have to wait and watch to see if it will be available later.

To quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh220561)

> Windows Phone applications are not able to directly access common
>   information stores such as the contacts list or to directly invoke
>   other applications such as phoning or messaging. To support scenarios
>   requiring common tasks such as phoning or messaging, the Windows Phone
>   provides a set of launcher and chooser APIs that enables applications
>   to access these useful phone features indirectly. **The launcher and chooser APIs invoke distinct built-in applications that replace the currently running application.**

Comment: But i've seen it in an application of the MarketPlace!

Comment: @Martech which one? It may be using a web based solution to send SMS messages but wouldn't be able to integrate with receiving them without directly integrating with the operators network.

Comment: "Who's near me" WNM:http://www.monwindowsphone.com/marketplace/who_27s_near_me-a1630.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Twilio Like service providers for achieving the requirement. They are providing bulk sms sending provision w/o the help of default wp7 SmsComposeTask

try this link http://www.twilio.com/